# Tomcat: Application errors when multiple WARs deployed

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am seeing something very strange after my Tomcat starts up. I have 15 applications deployed, and everything seems OK until I try to access a specific page on a specific application. There are some cross-dependencies such as services.

If I deploy the troubled application by itself, I can view the page without issue. If I deploy all the other applications one by one, I can view the page without issue. If all applications are deployed together at startup, this is when I see the following error:

> SEVERE: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
>       at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
>       at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1252)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1331)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1438)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:546)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at com.ideasx.stats.HttpFilterStatCounter.doFilter(HttpFilterStatCounter.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
>       ... 30 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
>       at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:159)
>       at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:130)
>       at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:103)
>       at org.apache.wicket.injection.ConfigurableInjector.inject(ConfigurableInjector.java:39)
>       at org.apache.wicket.injection.ComponentInjector.onInstantiation(ComponentInjector.java:52)
>       at org.apache.wicket.Application.notifyComponentInstantiationListeners(Application.java:1093)
>       at org.apache.wicket.Component.(Component.java:926)
>       at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.(MarkupContainer.java:113)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer.(WebMarkupContainer.java:49)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.(WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.java:51)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.(WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.java:43)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.(Panel.java:76)
>       at com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPanel.(BuyAGiftPanel.java:54)
>       at com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPage.(BuyAGiftPage.java:22)
>       ... 35 more

I have checked for dependency collisions and didn't find anything out of the ordinary. So my question is this. Given that I can deploy the applications in a specific order and not see the error, is it possible that Tomcat is responsible for this? How would I go about finding the problem?

Edited to add:
It seems that on startup, a clean session and the first request to the application throws the following cast exception:

> SEVERE: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
>       at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
>       at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>       at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1252)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1331)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1438)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:546)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at com.ideasx.stats.HttpFilterStatCounter.doFilter(HttpFilterStatCounter.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
>       ... 30 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:159)
>       at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:130)
>       at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:103)
>       at org.apache.wicket.injection.ConfigurableInjector.inject(ConfigurableInjector.java:39)
>       at org.apache.wicket.injection.ComponentInjector.onInstantiation(ComponentInjector.java:52)
>       at org.apache.wicket.Application.notifyComponentInstantiationListeners(Application.java:1093)
>       at org.apache.wicket.Component.(Component.java:926)
>       at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.(MarkupContainer.java:113)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer.(WebMarkupContainer.java:49)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.(WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.java:51)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.(WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup.java:43)
>       at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.(Panel.java:76)
>       at com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPanel.(BuyAGiftPanel.java:54)
>       at com.company.web.view.purchase.buy.BuyAGiftPage.(BuyAGiftPage.java:22)
>       ... 35 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerKey$$KeyFactoryByCGLIB$$7fb24d72 cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
>       at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:69)
>       ... 49 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to Tomcat it seems. After searching some more I found that cglib_nodep dependency has some class loading issues. I excluded this library from the tree, explicitly defined cglib version 2.2 and it cleared things up.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/flex/65337-an-strange-error-with-net-sf-cglib-core-keyfactory

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the server logs, all the temporary files in Tomcat and retry. This many times fix this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't seem to make any significant difference. I did notice however, that on a clean start of Tomcat and the first request to the application throws a casting exception. I've added that to my original post.